# Regarding audio recording audio using pulseaudio API

Tags: audio, ubuntu-12.04, audio-recording, pulseaudio

I cannot record audio using monitor source of sink devices,from 2 to 3 days.I have reinstalled Pulseaudio, but the problem remains. I am using ubuntu 12.04 with default pulse audio. few day ago, i  had same problem but I reinstalled ubuntu so I overcame problem but now same problem...??

from my point of view, Monitor of internal audio does not seem to get any signal.because 
   i check Pulse Audio Volume Control (pavucontrol), in which volume bar does not shown volume level in playtab and same case in output Devices tab.However, I can hear audio,and the pavucontrol Play tab shows the name of the applications which is running.

suggest any way to overcome this problem, because my application need audio recording from speaker(from context of pulse audio from sink device).

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, it was a simple case of the monitor being muted. In pavucontrol go to input devices, then in the show button at the bottom switch it to All input devices. I believe it's normally set to all except monitors, so the monitor doesn't show up. In my case it was this monitor that was muted, but I could still hear sound because the internal audio wasn't muted. sorry for pasting here but lets Hope it helps someone....